# Netty NIO SSL error when running out of filedescriptors

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, netty, nio

I am running a server performance test using a Netty based tester app as a client. The connection is over SSL sockets, where I send a registration and the server starts streaming data back. So I try to create as many connections as the server can handle.

I get up to about 4000 sockets on my tester until it (client OS process) runs out of filedescriptors due to too many open sockets. This would be fine if I got the proper error message from Netty. However, the only thing Netty gives me is: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException. This does not even have a stacktrace.

After various runs with the debugger, I believe this is due to io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler handling such errors as:

```
private static final ClosedChannelException CHANNEL_CLOSED = new ClosedChannelException();
    static {CHANNEL_CLOSED.setStackTrace(EmptyArrays.EMPTY_STACK_TRACE);}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // Make sure to release SSLEngine,
    // and notify the handshake future if the connection has been closed during handshake.
    setHandshakeFailure(ctx, CHANNEL_CLOSED);
    super.channelInactive(ctx);
}
```

In the end this results in throwing the ClosedChannelException with no stacktrace. If I run this over the debugger and set breakpoints in Netty earlier, this seems to be due to SSL Handshake timeout. I believe this timeout is due to running out of the filedescriptors. No idea why Netty treats it as a timeout though.

The reason for me to believe that it is running out of filedescriptors is due to earlier versions of this test getting exceptions for too many open files in the system. However, after reducing the use of files elsewhere in the code it now gets this far but I no longer get a meaningful error message. I also still get the error about too many open files if I run other software concurrently that keeps opening files at the time Netty hangs on this.

I am wondering if there is some trick for me to get Netty to properly report the actual cause of failure?

Here is the main relevant client init code:

```
  private static final EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

  public SSLClientNetty() throws Exception {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
    SSLEngine sslEngine = context.createSSLEngine();
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true);
    SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslEngine);
    //this is the time Netty waits before throwing the ClosedChannelException after reaching file limit
    sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeoutMillis(5000);
    try {
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
      b.group(group)
              .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
              .handler(new MyInitializer(sslHandler));

      ch = b.connect("localhost", 5555).sync().channel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error connecting to server", e);
      throw new RuntimeException("Error connecting to server", e);
    }
  }
```

The main relevant code for MyInitializer:

```
  @Override
  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ch.pipeline().addLast(sslHandler);
    ch.pipeline().addLast("bytesEncoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyDecoder());
  }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    super.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    log.error("Error in initializing connection", cause);
  }
```

In MyDecoder, just to make sure I also log any Exceptions:

```
  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    super.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    log.error("Error in decoder", cause);
    throw new RuntimeException("Error in decoder", cause);
  }
```

The main loop for tester creating connections:

```
while (true) {
  SSLClientNetty client = new SSLClientNetty();
  client.register();
  Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Right now the error msg is only this:

```
4000:...................java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

Where the tester is printing a dot for every successfully opened connection, and it ends with Netty throwing ClosedChannelException with no stacktrace (as explained above).

So, just to re-iterate, I am looking to get a better error report for what is actually causing the connections to fail. And to understand how Netty handles running out of sockets/how do I manage that..?

Comment: If that code is out of Netty it is one of the worst pieces of programming I have ever seen. They need to fix it. Exceptions should be thrown with stack traces, and ClosedChannelException should only be thrown for the reasons indicated in the Javadoc, preferably only by the the internals of the JDK.

Comment: You can see the Netty code in question at: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java. I agree it is not very good practice and the exception handling is difficult to figure out. There are actually three exceptions handled this way in that class. I guess I will look into some Netty mailing list with my question though.

Comment: The use of a static `ClosedChannelException` this way is actually reasonable for a number of reasons:
1. Exceptions are not cheap to create, especially deep in the stack (the cost goes up with every stack frame), and in a server application clients closing channels is very common - for performance this is a reasonable practice. 2. It is very likely that the JVM does not get any more info about *why* the channel was closed than "the channel was closed" from the OS - the only other vaguely reasonable choice would be `OutOfMemoryError` and people would draw the wrong conclusions from that

Comment: Thanks for your insights @TimBoudreau. However, in my case I ran it with a debugger and the next cause in the stack was an SSLHandshakeException. It would definitely have been more useful information to at least get that. I still am not sure how can I see when it runs out of filedescriptors etc. Anyway, I got around it for now, although always woule be nice to know more details. Maybe some flag could be an option to get more info?

Comment: @TimBoudreau The channel *isn't* closed by the OS, and that is *not* where the message came from. It is closed **by the application.** No other possibility. The exception remains incorrect.